# Find newest message from each sender?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nspredicate, pfquery

I've got a Messages menu in my app, and I'm completely at a loss on how to show the newest message received/sent from EACH user, without loading ALL messages received/sent.

I'm using Parse as my backend, so I've gotta believe there's some clever `subquery`, or `NSPredicate` that I could user for this.

The current solution I have in mind is another Boolean attribute for my messages, where all but the most recent get augmented, so I can known what to load with a simple predicate. This seems slopy though, save me from myself!

EDIT:

Right now I'm getting the messages where the user is the sender or receiver (depending on a segmented control), and then displaying each user who was sent to/received from with a sample of their newest message.

Right now I'm using internal logic to do this, and still in the process of figuring it out (the logic is a little backwards right now...)

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")

            if recievedOrSent {
            query.whereKey("other", equalTo: userName)
            print("called OTHER query")
        } else {
            query.whereKey("sender", equalTo: userName)
            print("called SENDER query")
        }

        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                    if thisSender == userName || self.recievedUsers.contains(thisSender) &&  self.lesserDate(thisTime, rhs: self.recievedUsersTimes[self.recievedUsers.indexOf(thisSender)!])
                    {} else {
                        self.recievedUsers.append(thisSender)
                        self.recievedUsersMsg.append(thisMessage)
                        self.recievedUsersTimes.append(thisTime)
                        self.recievedUsersMsgRead.append(thisRead)
                    }

                    if thisOther == userName || self.sentUsers.contains(thisOther) && self.lesserDate(thisTime, rhs: self.sentUsersTimes[self.sentUsers.indexOf(thisOther)!])
                    {} else {
                        self.sentUsers.append(thisOther)
                        self.sentUsersMsg.append(thisMessage)
                        self.sentUsersTimes.append(thisTime)
                        self.sentUsersMsgRead.append(thisRead)  
                }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post code of what you've tried so far? Date objects in Parse are comparable, meaning that you can use constraints such as lessThan, greaterThan and so on. You could query and sort the dates by descending (most recent first), constrain the results to each user, and then put a limit to 50 messages or whatever you desire.

Comment: Thanks @Russell! But I'm still failing to see how a limit and username constraint will get only the first from each user. Wouldn't that just the the first 50 who match the user, and have one of the usernames in common? If the user just had a 50 msg exchange with someone, that'd rule out other users. -MacLean

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I misunderstood your intentions. See below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only the *most recent* message from each user that you are having a conversation with, create a new class called `RecentMessage` and update it each time using an **afterSave cloud function** on the `Message` class.

In the afterSave hook, maintain a pointer in the `RecentMessage` class to the latest `Message` in the conversation for each user. Then all you have to do is query for all of the current user's `RecentMessage` objects and use `includeKey` on the `Message` pointer.

This let's you abstract away more logic from the client side and streamline your queries where performance really counts :)

Comment: Brilliant, I'm not used to cloud code, so I never would have thought of this. Thanks a ton, you're a life saver!!!

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help!